# how to convert a pro file of qt network to cmakelist

Tags: c++11, qmake, ros, qobject, qtnetwork

I have a pro file and I want to convert it to make a list to compile my code under ROS. But I still have many errors like errors with qobject, and the qbus classes.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

The pro file :

```
QT+= dbus
QT       += core gui
QT += network widgets


CONFIG+= c++11


SOURCES += \
main.cpp \
activenetwork.cpp

HEADERS += \
activenetwork.h
```

Comment: Hi, please put also the whole error which are you getting into the post for easier reaching the point, thanks. Btw- on the first look, is not that only the problem of formatting the file? I mean instead `QT       += core gui` eg `QT += core gui` etc.. ?

Comment: the error with the cmakelist:

erreur : QObject: No such file or directory